# Rails 3: How to write a migration to remove a model and it's tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an "Sqimage" (subquestion-image) model in my project. But later I created a "Qimage" model to replace "Sqimage"so I want to get rid of the old "Sqimage" model and the "Sqimage" table. I do not want to use

```
rake db:rollback
```

because if someone else uses the project later, he needs to run "rake db:rollbakck" manually again.
All I want to do is to create a new migration so that someone later can just run "rake db:migrate" to get everything done.
I searched the Rails Guide and found there was no command line instruction to create such a migration. So does anybody know how to write such a migration to delete the model and the table? What should the name of the class be, and what method should I use?
Here is the migration for creating the "Sqimage" model:

```
class CreateSqimages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sqimages do |t|
      t.belongs_to :subquestion
      t.string :directory

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :sqimages, :subquestion_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate a new migration which uses `drop_table` to remove the unneeded table. You can manually delete the model `.rb` file.

Comment: So if someone else runs the app, does he need to delete the .rb file manually again? In addition, what should the class name of the migration be? Sorry I am really a newbie...

Comment: Presumably you are keeping the project code in a source code repository (perhaps using git)? If you delete a file and commit that change to the repo, when another developer pulls your commits, the file will also be deleted from their copy of the project code. You can call the migration anything that tickles your fancy. If you want to be boring, maybe "remove_sqimage". More creative? Maybe "goodbye_sqimage_goodbye". Class name of the migration is derived from the file name, you can read the Rails Guides for details.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is what I did: I created a new migration called RemoveSqimages and added a method called up, inside which I added drop_table :sqimages. Then in command line I ran rails destroy model sqimage, which deleted the model migration, .rb file, textures and things like that. So now the migration to generate the sqimage model is gone, but the migration to delete the table is still there. Do I need to delete the migration file I just created to delete the table so that next time if somebody else uses it, it will not delete the table that does not exist at all?

Comment: If someone else starts with a new DB and runs `rake db:migrate`, then yes, that migration will cause an error. If they just directly load the schema with `rake db:schema:load`, it won't cause a problem. I would probably delete it.